# How to get the current base domain of a Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What's the idiomatic way to get a base domain for a Phoenix/Elixir app? Not of a single request, but a a base domain of an application, which probably depends on its current environment.

So locally it's should be `localhost`, but on a server, it can be "dev.my_domain.com", "my_domain.com" or something else that I can use in my Application.

I can, of course, add a special key in a `config/dev.exs` or `config/prod.exs`, but I thought that there might already be such a key somewhere which I can reuse.

Answer (score 15):

For requests, you should use the `host` field in the `Plug.Conn` like @TheAnhLe suggested.

But if you're looking to get the domain otherwise, Phoenix lets you specify the `url` parameter in your application `Endpoint` config:

```elixir
# config/prod.exs

config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "example.com", port: 80],
  # more configs...
```

You can use these methods to get the host's value:

```elixir
MyAppWeb.Endpoint.url()
# => "http://localhost:4000"

MyAppWeb.Endpoint.host()
# => "localhost"
```

This value defaults to `localhost` when not specified.

**Update:** For Phoenix versions prior to 1.3, replace `MyAppWeb` with `MyApp`.

Comment: For versions of Phoenix prior to 1.3, there was no MyApp vs MyAppWeb distinction and this answer is correct. For recent versions of Phoenix, it's MyAppWeb.Endpoint, not MyApp.Endpoint!

Answer (score 7):

With phoenix 1.3.0 (don't know about older versions) you can call `url/0` from [**Endpoint API**](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-endpoint-api)

For example:

```
iex(1)> TestWeb.Endpoint.url
"http://localhost:4000"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `host`.It's a request field stored in `Plug.Conn` struct.

> host - the requested host as a binary, example: "www.example.com"

[Request Fields](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#module-request-fields)

Comment: **Not of a single request,** !